# Prometheus unit test failing when adding "for" to alert

Tags: prometheus

With the following prometheus config:

```yaml
groups:
  - name: backup
    rules:
      - alert: BackupTooOld
        expr: time() - last_backup_success > 216000
        # for: 1h # 1m # 1s # <-- Setting any of these causes it to fail
        labels:
          severity: critical
        annotations:
          summary: "Backup too old"
          description: >-
            Backup for {{ $labels.path }} is over 2.5 days old.
```

...and the following test:

```yaml
rule_files:
  - alert.rules

evaluation_interval: 1m

tests:
  - name: backup
    interval: 1h
    input_series:
      - series: 'last_backup_success{path="gmail"}'
        values: '0x72'
      - series: 'last_backup_success{path="drive"}'
        values: '90000x72'

    alert_rule_test:
      - eval_time: 59h
        alertname: BackupTooOld
        exp_alerts: []

      - eval_time: 63h
        alertname: BackupTooOld
        exp_alerts:
          - exp_labels:
              severity: critical
              path: gmail
            exp_annotations:
              summary: Backup too old
              description: Backup for gmail is over 2.5 days old.
```

...everything works. However, changing the `alert` rule to add any nonzero `for` value (`1h`, `1m`, `1s`) causes the second test to fail - no matter how high I set the `eval_time`. What am I missing?

(Rationale for the `for` setting is that, on boot, the first check of `last_backup_success` takes a moment. I have tests for other alerts that set `for` which seem to work fine.)

Comment: Can you briefly explain why you are using "90000x72"? I`m trying to test time based alert rules but I cant get behind that. Thank you

Comment: The unit for `time` is seconds, so 90,000 seconds is 25 hours (just over one day). The idea here is that `path="drive"` succeeded, at the time of test, 63-25=38h ago, where the threshold is 60h. I'm not sure why I picked a number that high though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A non-zero `for` requires that the alert fires for at least two `evaluation_interval`s to make sure that it covers the requisite amount of time.

Here this is combining with that your time series are sparse, as they only have a data point once an hour so staleness is kicking in. This is unrealistic test data, an interval of 1m would be better.

In combination example the alert won't fire at 63h, but it should fire at 63h1m through 63h5m with a 1m `for`. A for longer than 5m can never fire given this test data.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, changing the interval to `1m`, the `input_series` length to `4320`, and setting `for: 1h` causes the test to succeed if-and-only-if `eval_time` for the second one is `61h1m` or greater.